# How to select comma separated values only in a loop?

Tags: dataframe, for-loop, split

Here is what I am trying to do.
suppose this is my data column.

```
0                               ET Bureau
1                By Sobia Khan, ET Bureau
2                               ET Bureau
3            By Sarita C Singh, ET Bureau
4    By Dipanjan Roy Chaudhury, ET Bureau
```

Here I want to run a loop and select only those values which are having comma separated values, for ex in the above data at index 1 there is a comma separated value and from that value, I need to extract only the string which is after the comma for ex from By Sobia Khan, ET Bureau I need ET Bureau only.

I tried `df['column_name'].str.split(',').str[1]` but it was giving me nan values for the ones which were not comma separated. So I want to run a loop only for comma separated values.

Comment: Use a selector on your dataframe to only process rows containing a comma.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a pattern to match all before the comma, then the comma and optional whitespace chars.

Capture in a group 1 or more characters following after the first comma and use that in the replacement.

```
[^,\r\n]*,\s*(.+)
```

- `[^,\r\n]*` Match any char except a comma or a newline
- `,\s*` Match the comma and optional whitespace chars
- `(.+)` Capture group 1, match 1+ times any char (Referred to as `\1` in the replacement)

For example

```
data = [
    ['ET Bureau'],
    ['By Sobia Khan, ET Bureau'],
    ['ET Bureau'],
    ['By Sarita C Singh, ET Bureau'],
    ['By Dipanjan Roy Chaudhury, ET Bureau']
]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['column_name'])
df['column_name'] = df['column_name'].str.replace(r"[^,\r\n]*,\s*(.+)", r"\1")
print(df)
```

Output

```
0   ET Bureau
1   ET Bureau
2   ET Bureau
3   ET Bureau
4   ET Bureau
```